# Efficiency of joins between tables partitioned by different time granularities

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery, there are tables partitioned by different time granularities. For example:

- Table A is partitioned by day
- Table B is partitioned by hour

Joins between tables A and B will be less efficient than if both tables were partitioned by day? How this join could be optimized?

Answer (score 0):

When you join tables partitioned by different time granularities, the join will be less efficient than if both tables were partitioned by the same time granularity. This is because BigQuery has to scan more partitions to complete the join operation.
It follows then that to optimize this join, you can repartition one of the tables so that it is partitioned by the same time granularity as the other table.